# importing scala classes into matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, scala, jvm

I haven't looked very deeply at all at this, but I've recently learned that it is possible to `import` Java classes into the matlab workspace. This actually made me wonder if it was possible to import *Scala* classes as well. A quick Google search didn't reveal much. I was wondering if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.  Scala classes are just regular classes; use them the same way as you would a Java class.  (Just beware of classloader issues.  I routinely trip on them when trying to use Java or Scala classes in Matlab.)